# JS conversion to LWC - Image Capture

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I'm working on the user image capture function and as a new member of LWC community, I need a bit of help on converting JS to LWC component.

It is supposed to ask users to get access to the camera and then capture the image(and image unique data) on the pressing button.

.js

```
let camera_button = document.querySelector("#start-camera");
let video = document.querySelector("#video");
let click_button = document.querySelector("#click-photo");
let canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");

// open camera
camera_button.addEventListener('click', async function() {
    let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false });
    video.srcObject = stream;
});

// capture image
click_button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    let image_data_url = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');

    // data url of the image
    console.log(image_data_url);
});
```

.html

```
<button id="start-camera">Start Camera</button>
<video id="video" width="320" height="240" autoplay></video>
<button id="click-photo">Click Photo</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="240"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly, it just involves shuffling the code around a little bit.

Attach the event listeners in the markup:

```
<button onclick={startCamera}>Start Camera</button>
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay></video>
<button onclick={clickPhoto}>Click Photo</button>
<canvas width="320" height="240"></canvas>
```

Note that we can't use ID values, nor do we need them, since we now attach the handlers directly to the elements, and the remaining elements are unique, so a normal `querySelector` works here.

And then handle those events just as you would in any JavaScript ES6-style class:

```
  async startCamera() {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false });
    const video = this.template.querySelector('video');
    video.srcObject = stream;
  }

  // capture image
  clickPhoto() {
    const video = this.template.querySelector('video');
    const canvas = this.template.querySelector('canvas');
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    const image_data_url = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
    // data url of the image
    console.log(image_data_url);
  }
```

Note: this code won't work in Locker Service. You must use [Lightning Web Security](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_lwsec_enable) to have a chance of this working inside Salesforce.

[Demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/5NQXEYUCIsr2TAyZATPm/src/app.js?p=stories).

Comment: Hey @sfdcfox it's you again! I always learn everything from you and I greatly greatly appreciate things from you. I will try this and let you know more after I play around with this. Thanks again.